# Is Lyanna Mormont the Lady of Bear Island on the show? (in contrast with the books)

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the books Lyanna's mother [Maege](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maege_Mormont) is Lady of House Mormont. Lyanna also has other siblings that go in line before her. She does seem to have some authority because she was the one to respond to Stannis's letter but I think that was simply because all her siblings and her mother were not at Bear Island at the moment according to the wiki page of Maege:

> Lady Maege is mentioned by her oldest surviving daughter, Alysane, when asked about her siblings by Asha Greyjoy. She is with two of her other daughters, Lyra and Jory, though it is not said where, while her youngest, Lyanna is back on Bear Island.

In the show it does seem that Lyanna is in charge of everything or is that also simply because the rest is not at home?

Comment: Don't think mom gets to take charge, since she'd technically not of the bloodline of the house (Lannister-love excepted, for that house).  She might get to act in some kind of Regent status.

I think they removed the mom and siblings because they aren't key to the story, and having the Starks have to grovel to a child for a handful of knights, then having her shame the northern lords added to the TV experience.

Comment: @AndrewMattson Lady Maege was actually of the bloodline of House Mormont. She is sister of Lord Jeor Mormont. Jeor Mormont went to wall, which made his son Jorah Mormont Lord of Bear Island. Jorah, only son of Jeor, went into exile without fathering a child. Due to which, Maege Mormont inherited the Island. Now that Maege is dead according to Show, her daughter Lyanna has inherited the Island according to show

Comment: My bad, thanks for putting the facts on the record.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Books

Maege Mormont has following daughters:

1. Dacey Mormont
2. Alysane Mormont
3. Lyra Mormont
4. Jorelle Mormont
5. Lyanna Mormont

Dacey was murdered at Red Wedding. Alysane apparently came back to Bear Islands because she was part of Stannis's liberation of Deepwood Motte. Lyra Mormont was last with her Lady Mother who went on Robb's orders to find Lord Reed, they have disappeared. Jorelle is also with them.

Which leaves Lyanna the Mormont in Bear Island as Alysane is on the march with Stannis. She was on Bear Island because she was not with her Mother in Riverlands, and because she replied to Stannis' summons in ADWD:

> Bear Island knows no king but the King in the North, whose name is
>   STARK.

But since she is the youngest daughter and second daughter of Lady Maege is alive and free, it appears she is filling the place of Alysane in books, rather than being in charge in her own right.

You must keep it in mind that when Lyanna replied Stannis, it was before He moved against Ironborn. Only explanation for that can be that Alysane must be away.

Afterwards when Stannis moved against the Ironborn, It was Alysane who lead the surprise Mormont attack on Ironborn and later swore fealty to Stannis on behalf of her house.

In any case, Alysane is the heir, not Lyanna.

### Show

In the show, No other Children of Lady Maege Mormont are mentioned and Lyanna is mentioned as Lady of Bear Island. So it appears, in show canon, Lyanna is the only Child of Lady Maege and thus inherited the Island on her Mother's demise.

Maege's death is not shown on the Show but it is implied because in Season 5, Stannis refers to Lyanna as Lady of Bear Island.

As pointed out by [BCdotWEB](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31029/bcdotweb), Lyanna said this in Episode "Broken Man" to confirm her mother's death:

> "My mother wasn't a great beauty or any other kind of beauty. She was
>   a great warrior, though. She died fighting for your brother, Robb."

Comment: This seems like it's an answer based on the books? The question seems to be about the situation in the show, as opposed to the books. Were any of these other daughters actually in the show?

Comment: @DCShannon Updated with show info

Comment: Nice job, because it makes books vs show somewhat irrelevant.  We can remember that when Robb and Catelyn went to war, Brandon was left running Winterfell with a hefty assist from advisors, which could be what was demonstrated with the Mormont clan, except the precocious young Mormont is not lacking in any confidence.

Comment: @AndrewMattson Lyanna appears to be a stronger ruler than Bran no doubts. She is however also surrounded by her own advisors, as shown in the episode when Jon and Sansa went to meet her

Comment: "My mother wasn't a great beauty or any other kind of beauty. She was a great warrior, though. She died fighting for your brother, Robb." -- quote from "The Broken man"